# Group by and min (nested select)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, nested

I have data on picklist time stamps that I need to categorize by time. For each record, I have a unitID, a timestamp(in datetime format), a location, and a quantity. similar to this.

```
UNIT  TIME   LOCATN   Picks
A    11:50    L4       2
B    11:51    m6       3
C    12:01    L8       4
B    12:03    A4       2
A    12:05    B6       3
C    12:06    C7       1
B    12:10    D7       4
```

I need to group these by time intervals 
so my desired output would be

```
TIME    UNITS    picks
11:00    2         14
12:00    1         5
```

@ 11, its 2 units because 2 units started in that hour, 14 picks because all of the picks for orders A + B amount to 15. while @12, only C is accounted for because that is when it starts.

This is because units A + B started before 12:00, so I don't want my query counting them both as 2 different orders, in two different time "zones"

AS you can see, I want to group them by when the unit starts and count all picks for that order as part of the time interval when it started. not all active units during an hour, and if i do a normal select and group by, I would get something like

```
Time   UNIT     picks
11:00   2         5
12:00   3         14
```

So if then if I have 100 orders in the data set, I run a normal grouping query and get a total of 120 orders, because it splits the orders. I need to categorize my unit by the lowest timestamp it has.

Comment: How is your time stored?  Text?

Comment: Grouping by hour is simple... how on earth did you get to 14 for 11:00?  ps. Show us what you've tried already.

Comment: I think the OP has reversed the values for `picks`.

Comment: Sorry, im new to this site and having a really tough time formatting this easy to read. the data is already stored as datetime. I got 14 because I want it to categorize A + B as units part of the 11:00 group and only C as 12:00. basically, I have picklist data, I want to find number of lists completed by hour. The problem is when these picklists go across hour boundaries it counts it as being in both, so I get multiple count units.

Comment: So IF I have 9000 orders and create a table counting how many orders were completed each hour, I get a sum of 10000 orders because some cross the boundary.

Comment: You need to edit your question, and include all this -- you have nothing labelled as A/B/C -- and what "boundary" do you mean?  The hour?  How can a datetime cross an hour?  And show us what you've tried please, maybe that will help us understand.

Comment: Sorry, I tried adding a photo for better clarification, but I " need 10 points to post an image". I will try and clarify this best I can. I have a table that has timestamps for a pick that is part of an order. so each row has a field UNITID, time, location, quantity.  There are multiple records assigned to each unitID. I want to categorize them by when the order started, so the min value of time for that specific unitID.

Comment: Please click EDIT on your question and fix it (we dont need a picture).  Show us the whole table schema please (or tables).  Show sample source data, and output.  Explain the relationships.  Explain your logic.  You keep mentioning order, but I don't see an order ID...  We can't help you if you don't show us all your cards.  And again, show us what you have tried (your query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes the assumption that your [TIME] field is actually a TIME datatype - CAST() may be necessary.

```
-- sample data
DECLARE @StackOverflow TABLE (Unit INT, [TIME] TIME, Locatn VARCHAR(2), Picks INT)
INSERT INTO @StackOVerflow (Unit, [Time], Locatn, Picks) 
SELECT 1,     '11:50','L4',       2 UNION 
SELECT 2,     '11:51','m6',       3 UNION 
SELECT 3,     '12:01','L8',       4 UNION 
SELECT 2,     '12:03','A4',       2 UNION 
SELECT 1,     '12:05','B6',       3 UNION 
SELECT 3,     '12:06','C7',       1 UNION 
SELECT 1,     '12:10','D7',       4

-- confirm sample data
SELECT * FROM @StackOverflow

-- actual output
SELECT 
    DATEPART(HOUR,b.MinTime) StartHour,
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.Unit) Units,
    SUM(a.Picks) Picks
FROM 
    @StackOverflow a
     INNER JOIN 
      (
        SELECT Unit, MIN([TIME]) MinTime
        FROM @StackOverflow
        GROUP BY Unit 
      ) b ON 
        a.Unit = b.Unit
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(HOUR,b.MinTime)
```

Comment: You sir, are clairvoyant!

Comment: @JiggsJedi, I had to be on this one :)  ColinSinclair, even though an answer has been found, I'd still recommend that you go back through the comments, figure out what edits need to be made to your question, and then make them: the best thanks you can offer to myself or any of the half dozen people who tried to help you today would be to learn how to write the question more clearly next time. That helps everyone.

Comment: I do apologize for that. By trying to make it sound simpler, I made it much more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

For what you've explained so far:

```
Select
    To_Char(Time, HH) || ':00' as TimeHour,
    UNIT as UNIT,
    Sum(Picks) as Picks
From
    Table x
Group By
    To_Char(Time, HH)
    UNIT
```

Answer (score 0):

I derived a field, called Interval to facilitate the grouping you're looking for.

Take a look at the solution on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7ba1/21/0).

Answer (score 0):

if u use mySQL then u should try this one

```
mysql> select hour(time), count(unit), sum(picks) from picklist group by hour(time);
```

the result will be like this

```
 hour(time) count(unit) sum(picks)
```

`11         2           5 
     12         2           7`